# Django datetime loaded incorrectly from database

Tags: python, django, timezone

I have a Django application for viewing sensor observations. This is my observation model:

```py
class Observation(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
```

In one of my views, I want to use the timestamp of the latest observation:

```py
latest_observation = Observation.objects.order_by('-timestamp').values('timestamp').first()
context['latest_data_timestamp'] = latest_observation['timestamp'] if latest_observation else None
```

The timestamp is stored correctly in the database (UTC). However, when running my view, the timestamp is changed to the timezone set in `settings.py`, but the `tzinfo` is still `'UTC'`.

Timezone support is enabled in `settings.py`:

```py
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
USE_TZ = True
```

For example, a timestamp stored in the database as `2023-11-22 18:00:00+00:00` is loaded as `2023-11-22 19:00:00+00:00`, but if I understand it correctly, it should be `2023-11-22 19:00:00+01:00`. (Ignoring daylight saving time, `'Europe/Amsterdam'` is `UTC+1`)

I'm using Django 4.2.7 with PostgreSQL for production and SQLite for development, but the problem is there in both environments.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

I tried using `astimezone` to set the timezone correctly, but that doesn't work. I could also simply replace the `tzinfo`, but it feels like a hacky solution. There's probably a better way...

Comment: Which database are you using, and what data type is the `Observation.timestamp` field in the db?  Also, what version of Django are you running?

Comment: Good question, I added the database(s) and the Django version that I'm using. How can I find the data type in the database?

Comment: Django doesn't support non-UTC default time zones when using SQLite, due to lack of time zone support in SQLite itself.  PostgreSQL and SQLite are quite different in this regard.  But you probably should not set a default time zone at all.  See my answer for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#time-zone) on the `TIME_ZONE` option:

> - If the database backend doesn't support time zones (e.g. **SQLite**, MySQL, Oracle), Django reads and writes datetimes in local time according to this option if it is set and in UTC if it isn't.
>
>   - If Django manages the database and you don’t have a strong reason to do otherwise, you should leave this option unset.
>
>   ...

So that explains the results from your development environment using SQLite.

PostgreSQL behaves differently in this regard.  From the same docs:

> - If the database backend supports time zones (e.g. **PostgreSQL**), the `TIME_ZONE` option is very rarely needed. It can be changed at any time; the database takes care of converting datetimes to the desired time zone.
>
>   ...

So either way, you should probably set only `USE_TZ = True`, but *not* set the `TIME_ZONE` option.  Only set the `TIME_ZONE` option when connecting to a legacy database that stores its date/time values in local time.  If you're storing time in UTC, you should not use the `TIME_ZONE` option.

Instead, use the `timezone.activate` function, to set the user's display time zone to a particular time zone.

Some of this is also explained [in the Django docs on time zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones).